# how to get visual force form input field value from apex class?

Tags: visualforce

I need to pass input field value from visual force page to the controller. This input value is not belongs to any object. It just a normal input value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you include your code then people will be more inclined to help.

Answer (score 2):

The bindings doesn't require an object to work, just getters and setters.
Let's suppose you want to ask for the user name, and store it in a variable.

The controller has to have the variable to store the name:

```
public String userName {get;set;}
```

And the visualforce page just need to have an `apex:inputfield` pointing to that variable:

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!userName}" />
```

If you want to pre populate that variable so the input displays something when the page loads just set the value on the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling with the same issue today and still haven't found a general solution to that which I can simply set the value in javascript. However, this blog post: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-apex-method-from.html will probably help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a controller extension class and in the extension class create a property for your variable.

Essentially use a  wrapper class. You can then access the value in VF using

```
{!var}
```

and in your extension class, you can access it as var.